Magento 2.4.5-p8 with CSP on scripts inserted by Google Tag Manager
We're updating our Magento from 2.4.5-p7 to 2.4.5-p8.
As you know, in Magento 2.4.5-p8 the CSP on the checkout page is now restrict mode instead of report-only.
We know now that the scripts inserted through our magento's modules/theme must be rendered using the $secureRenderer (example in the image below)
SecureRenderer working well
And the external domains must be added as whitelist (example in the image below)
whitelist working well
But we still have problem loading scripts through Google Tag Manager.
It's reporting that the inline script will not be loaded (example in the image below)
csp error on loading the GTM script
The script (example in the image below)
GTM script we are tying do load
References:
https://experienceleague.adobe.com/en/docs/commerce-operations/release/notes/security-patches/2-4-5-patches
https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/security/content-security-policies/
How can we insert a script through GTM while preserving the CSP?
I don't have any clue of how can I load a script through GTM.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I have managed to find a solution to this problem. Let me detail my steps and perhaps this could be of assistance to someone else.
Following on from this document on Google Developers page: https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/security/guides/csp
We can create an override to the Google Tag Manager component. In my example, I just made an inline Google Tag Manager instead of using the Magento component system - you of course could do it using the prescribed extension technique, but I personally kept it simple for simplicity and I also feel the component system overcomplicates an already very complicated framework.
Steps:
Add a sequence to your module.xml for your module to ensure Magento_GoogleTagManager loaded first.
```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="ACME_OverrideTag" setup_version="1.0.0">
            <sequence>
                <module name="Magento_GoogleTagManager"/>
            </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Add layout file to override the tag entry: app/code/ACME/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="head.additional">
            <block class="Magento\GoogleTagManager\Block\Ga" name="google_analyticsuniversal" as="google_analyticsuniversal"
                   template="ACMA_OverrideTag::ga.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Lastly, add the .phtml and override the tag script (adjust accordingly for the original - note that I'm passing the nonce to google tag manager, like in the documentation:
app/code/ACME/OverrideTag/view/frontend/templates/ga.phtml
```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright Â© Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
?>
<?php
/** @var \Magento\GoogleTagManager\Block\Ga $block */
/** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Helper\SecureHtmlRenderer $secureRenderer */

$accountType = $block->getConfig(\Magento\GoogleTagManager\Helper\Data::XML_PATH_TYPE);
$gtmAccountId = $block->getConfig(\Magento\GoogleTagManager\Helper\Data::XML_PATH_CONTAINER_ID);
$gapAccountId = $block->getConfig(\Magento\GoogleTagManager\Helper\Data::XML_PATH_ACCOUNT);
switch ($accountType) {
    case \Magento\GoogleTagManager\Helper\Data::TYPE_TAG_MANAGER:
        if (!empty($gtmAccountId)) {
            /** @var \Magento\Csp\Helper\CspNonceProvider $nonceProvider */
            $nonceProvider = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(\Magento\Csp\Helper\CspNonceProvider::class);
            $nonce = $nonceProvider->generateNonce();
            $currencyCode = $block->escapeJs($block->getStoreCurrencyCode());
            $orderData = json_encode($block->getOrdersDataArray());
            ?>
            <?php
            $scriptString = <<<script
            window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
              dataLayer.push({
                'nonce': '{$nonce}'
              });
              window.dlCurrencyCode = "{$currencyCode}";

                // Collect and send data about order and items
                let orderData = {$orderData};
                if (orderData > 0) {
                    
                    $.each(orderData, function (index, value) {
                        dataLayer.push(value);
                    });
                }
                    (function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
            new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
            j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
            'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;var n=d.querySelector('[nonce]');
            n&&j.setAttribute('nonce',n.nonce||n.getAttribute('nonce'));f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
            })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','{$gtmAccountId}');
            script;
            echo $secureRenderer->renderTag('script', [], $scriptString, false);
            ?>

            <!-- END GOOGLE TAG MANAGER -->
            <?php
        }
        break;
    case \Magento\GoogleTagManager\Helper\Data::TYPE_UNIVERSAL:
        if (!empty($gapAccountId)) {
            ?>
            <!-- BEGIN GOOGLE UNIVERSAL ANALYTICS CODE -->
            <script type="text/x-magento-init">
            {
                "*": {
                    "Magento_GoogleAnalytics/js/google-analytics": {
                        "isCookieRestrictionModeEnabled": <?= (int)$block->isCookieRestrictionModeEnabled() ?>,
                        "currentWebsite": <?= (int)$block->getCurrentWebsiteId() ?>,
                        "cookieName": "<?= /* @noEscape */ \Magento\Cookie\Helper\Cookie::IS_USER_ALLOWED_SAVE_COOKIE ?>",
                        "ordersTrackingData": <?= /* @noEscape */ json_encode($block->getOrdersTrackingData()) ?>,
                        "pageTrackingData": <?= /* @noEscape */ json_encode($block->getPageTrackingData($gapAccountId)) ?>
                    }
                }
            }
            </script>
            <!-- END GOOGLE UNIVERSAL ANALYTICS CODE -->
            <?php
        }
        break;
}
```

Then in Google Tag Manager, you need to run through a few steps:

Go to Tag Manager account, select "Variables"

In User-Defined Variables at the bottom, add "New"
** Type: Data Layer Variable
** Data Layer Variable Name : "nonce"
** Data Layer Version: Version 1

Save this variable

In your affected scripts in the tags, where you put the javascript, change it to:
<script nonce="{{nonce}}">



The nonce will be passed through to the script and will operate normally.

While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - From Review

I am not sure where you are trying to insert js code, but if you are trying to insert GTM code in .phtml file then you can use following script
<?php $scriptString = <<<script

<-- gtm js code goes here-->

script;
?>

<?= / @noEscape / $secureRenderer->renderTag('script', ['type' => 'text/javascript'], $scriptString, false) ?>

